# Does Haskell have an eager version of `foldr`?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation, fold

The [Foldr Foldl Foldl'](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27) wiki page describes the differences between `foldr` and `foldl`. Both process lists from left-to-right, but `foldr` accumulates the result from right-to-left whereas `foldl` does so from left-to-right.

The page goes on to discourage the use of `foldl` in favor of the eager version `foldl'`, which is more efficient.

Is there a corresponding eager version of `foldr`, presumably called `foldr'`? If so, is there a reason that it isn't mentioned on the wiki page?

Answer (score 9):

There's no need for `foldr'`, sonce one can always use `foldr f` with a *strict* `f` to achieve the same goal.

We could define it...

```
foldr' f a xs = foldr f' a xs
  where f' x y = seq x (seq y (f x y))
```

... but it's simpler to pass a strict `f` at the call point instead, if needed.

Comment: Why would anyone want to pass a strict version of `f` here? Are there any performance benefits?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. `f` strict on `x` can be useful. Strict on `y` less so.

Comment: It looks like strictness on `y` is *strictly* counterproductive.

Answer (score 4):

A quick [Hoogle search](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=foldr%27) shows that there is, indeed, a `foldr'` defined in `Data.Foldable`.

I assume the reason it isn't mentioned on the linked page is that it isn't relevant to the problem of stack overflows discussed there.  When calculating a sum using `foldr (+) 0` on a large list, the stack overflow that may occur isn't a result of lazy application of the operator `(+)`.  Rather, it occurs because a fundamental feature of a right fold (whether strict or lazy) is that the most deeply nested application of the operator occurs at the end of the list.  For an operator like `(+)` that requires evaluation of both operands to yield any sort of result, this means that either `foldr` or `foldr'` must build up an O(n) stack of continuations before getting to the end of the list where the `(+)` operator can start to do "real work".

Answer (score 0):

Both `foldr` and `foldl'` are extremely useful for lists. Neither `foldl` nor `foldr'` is often useful for lists. But these days, those functions are actually methods of the `Foldable` class, and they *are* useful for some instances. To take an extreme example, consider snoc lists:

```
data SL a = SL a :> a | Nil
infixl 5 :>

instance Foldable SL where
  foldMap _ Nil = mempty
  foldMap f (xs :> x) = foldMap f xs <> f x

  foldl _ b Nil = b
  foldl f b (xs :> x) = f (foldl f b xs) x

  foldr' _ n Nil = n
  foldr' c n (xs :> x) =
    let n' = c x n
    in n' `seq` foldr' c n' xs
```

For snoc lists, `foldl` and `foldr'` are really useful, while `foldr` and `foldl'` are pretty much useless!

Many `Foldable` containers can make good use of all four of these methods. For example, `Data.Set.Set`, `Data.Map.Map k` and `Data.Sequence.Seq` can each be folded perfectly well in either direction.

```
import Data.Sequence (Seq)
import qualified Data.Sequence as S

toForwardList :: Seq a -> [a]
toForwardList = foldr (:) []

toReverseList :: Seq a -> [a]
toReverseList = foldl (flip (:)) []
```

The forward and reverse conversions are equally efficient and equally lazy.